# Laravel 5, check if class is registered in the container

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there any way to check if a class exists in Laravel 5?

I had this solution for Laravel 4: try to make a specific class, and if I get a `ReflectionException`, I use a generic class.
In Laravel 5 looks like I can't intercept the `ReflectionException` and I get a "Whoops".

I was wondering if there is some better way to do this.

```
try {
    $widgetObject = \App::make($widget_class);
} catch (ReflectionException $e) {
    $widgetObject = \App::make('WidgetController');
    $widgetObject->widget($widget);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Check whether your class is set in bindings by doing

```
app()->bound($classname);
```

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just use the PHP function [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)?

```
if(class_exists($widget_class)){
    // class exists
}
```

Comment: Well, maybe I did not use the right term; the class of course does not exist for php until it has been injected by laravel. App::make should inject the class or return a ReflectionError if it can't file the class' file.

Comment: But after all maybe it works... It's really so easy? Thank you!

Comment: I see... Actually catching `ReflectionException` should work. Are you maybe missing an import statement or backslash? `\ReflectionException $e`

Comment: Good guess, probably you're right. With this thing of namespacing everything Laravel 5 has lost a lot of his freshness, I think. And chasing all the facades to put a \ before them is difficult.

Comment: There's no need to put a backslash before Facades. They are all aliased in the global namespace

Answer (score 4):

`\App::bound()` might be the proper way.

Latest laravel versions (Maybe >= 5.3, I don't know exactly) register service providers in alittle different way by default.

For example, a new way of registering:

```
$this->app->singleton(MyNamespace\MyClass::class, function()
{
    /* do smth */ }
);
```

instead of the old one:

```
$this->app->singleton('MyClassOrAnyConvenientName', function()
{
    /* do smth */ }
);
```

As a result we should use `App::make('\MyNamespace\MyClass')` instead of `App::make('MyClassOrAnyConvenientName')` to resolve a service.

We maintain a library which has to support both versions. So we use `\App::bound()` to determine whether old or new format of service name is registered in container. `class_exists()` did actually work for newer laravel but didn't work as expected for older ones because in old systems we didn't have a properly named `Facade` for that service (Facade's name differed from registered service name) and `class_exists()` returned `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the getProvider method on the Application container:

```
if (app()->getProvider($classname)) {
   // Do what you want when it exists.
 }
```

It's been available since 5.0 and can be viewed [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L523).

Comment: ```app()->getProvider($classname)``` is not working when Provider using Class auto discovery which is available after laravel 6.